# Method Range of object _Worksheet failed when copying cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I know similar questions have been asked but I have read them and I still can not figure out what is going wrong. I have a workbook with 4 worksheets in it.

The Sub below is just the start of a process to create a specifically formatted document so there is more to come but it is failing at the very first copy. I have tried replacing the variables output and reqSheet with `Worksheets("Requests")` and `Worksheets("Output")` but it still throws the same error.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

```
Sub generateOutput(requests As Integer)
Dim i As Integer
Dim output As Excel.Worksheet
Dim reqSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set reqSheet = Worksheets("Requests")
Set output = Worksheets("Output")

i = 0
Do While (i < requests)
output.Range("A" & i).Value = reqSheet.Range("A" & i).Value    'This line fails
i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Error message:

> Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First loop iteration would produce output.Range("A0").Value = reqSheet.Range("A0").Value, which is invalid. Excel uses a one-based row index.

However, if `requests` is small (say, below 50k), I would use the following approach:

```
Sub generateOutput(requests As Integer)
    Dim output As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim reqSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Set reqSheet = Worksheets("Requests")
    Set output = Worksheets("Output")

    output.Range("A1:A" & requests).Value = reqSheet.Range("A1:A" & requests).Value
End Sub
```